# beginner python translator: I am unable to convert a list from shelve module into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple translator that from a dictionary in a shelve module I can type words in English and the program translates the input word by word and then puts the results into a .txt file. This is pretty much what I have so far.

```
import shelve

s = shelve.open("THAI.dat")
entry = input("English word")
define = input("Thai word")
s[entry]=define

text_file = open("THAI.txt", "w+")
trys = input("Input english word")

if trys in s:
    print(s[trys])
    part = s[trys]
    text_file.write(part)
```

this is where the error appears. I think the problem is that part is a list and is should be a string to be able to be written to a .txt file. What should I do. I am just a beginner so I am probably missing something basic. This is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austen\Desktop\phython fun\thai translator.py", line 29, in <module>
    text_file.write(part)
TypeError: must be str, not list
>>>
```

at the end I would like to be able to do this

```
text_file.readlines()
```

and then be able to even go into the text file and see the translation.

Comment: Can you give us the exact error?  (You should always do this on the site)  Thanks

Comment: `s[entry]=[define]` should be just `s[entry]=define`

Comment: @Cameron You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I changed that and still got the same error.

Comment: @AustenNovis With that change it works for me. Check you saved the change.

Comment: @Austen Novis: Maybe you reused the existing storage that already has lists in it. Delete the THAI.dat and start from scratch.

Comment: If this really is THAI, as in the language, you will need to use UTF-8 to read and write the file.

Comment: @Lattyware: Someone else can have the rep. I didn't know the whole answer, just that that line wasn't right ;-)

Comment: Well, it needs an answer so it can be answered, so I created one.

Comment: thanks i guys. Cameron was correct, but the reason is wasn't working after I changed that was because I was using THAI letters @drewk how do I use UTF-8? I am new to programming and looked online, but couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, besides not having `s[entry]=[define]`, I think you need to read and write a Thai file using the right codec.

Assuming the file `thai.dat` was written with UTF-8 (an assumption) you now need to compare the strings using the same codec and the write your data file with the same codec.

As a start, try this line from your command shell:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.getdefaultencoding()'
```

If it prints `ascii` then you may need to set your default encoding to UTF-8 or the string comparisons will not work properly.

Also, you need open the output file in UTF-8 mode like so:

```
>>>import codecs
>>>f = codecs.open("THAI.txt", "w+", "utf-8")
```

Then write to this file as usual.